# detect if file is being used in blackberry

Tags: file, blackberry

I was wishing that I could detect if a file is being used in blackberry or is open in blackberry. Can some one tell me how to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that a file is available to be processed, then use `try-catch` and try to open the file. If there's sharing violation condition you will go to the `catch` section and can process this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael Osipov.

Actually, I had to delete some files in a particular directory in my Blackberry. And for this I open my file as:

FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(filePath,Connector.READ_WRITE);

The code is giving me IOException as : File system error (12) when I try to execute: 
fc.delete();

I think this Exception is because the file is open. What should I do in this case?

Comment: If some files/folders are locked there's no workaround in RIM API to delete them. But you can display a message to user, that some files/folders were not deleted and ask user to delete them manually.